# Test automation of two mobile applications communicating eachother

Tags: java, selenium, mobile, automated-tests, appium

I want to know is it possible to automate two application communicating each other. I'll explain my requirement with two examples just for you ti understand.

Example 1 - Let's take a taxi booking application. Passenger app will send a request to Driver app. Driver app is installed in driver's phone and Passenger app is installed in clients phone,
When Passenger app sends a request, driver app receives an alert, and then driver accepts the hire request. (driver must accept the request within 30 seconds)

Example 2 - A payment app,
Let's say there is a merchant app and customer app. When we enter some amount to the merchant app, it will generate a QR code, this code then will be scanned from customer app and the customer can pay with already saved, credit card.

While one app is running the other app should run, because if we close the first app, the current state of the app is lost. Since one app is waiting till the other app's response and based on the response the 1st app will continue the flow. So one app is waiting till other app's responds(ex: within 15 seconds driver app should response)

**How to simulate this using Appium, Java, Selenium to perform automation testing with the use of emulator or real device?**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

Writing your tests, all you need to do is assert expected behaviors at an appropriate time. You can access multiple apps depending on the design of your tests.

Capabilities can change during the test run and the app that you're accessing would change accordingly. A flow graph would be somewhat like:-

1. Set driver capabilities for  X app.
2. Launch app X and perform tasks as desired there.
3. Assert that these tasks have been completed.
4. Close the driver, set new driver capabilities for Y app.
5. Launch the Y app and perform assertions on the expected behavior on that app.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the solution. How can we run both apps parallel and wait for the inputs to be provided from one app to the other to continue the flow. Lets say app x send data to app 2, then app 2 send again some data to app 1 to continue the process.Thank you...

Comment: @SanojIndrasinghe I am proposing a sequential run itself. What I would be interested in rather is, what task from a UI perspective do you think needs such a parallel execution and validation.

Comment: For example, when passenger app send a request to driver app, once driver accept the request within 15 seconds. Then passenger app should display that the driver accepted the request and hes on the way. If client press cancel while driver on the way, then driver app should display the booking is cancelled. Both apps running parallel by two types of users.

Comment: While one app is running the other app should run, because if we close the first app, the current state of the app is lost. Since one app is waiting till the other app response and based on the response the app will continue the flow. So one app is waiting till other app responds(ex: within 15 seconds driver app should response) How can we achieve this if we close the 1st app and launch 2nd app?

Comment: @SanojIndrasinghe That would majorly depend on the time you display the attributes on an UI. Moreover, these kind of validations are better done at n API level.

Answer (score 0):

Start two appium sessions `appium -p 4723` and `appium -p 4727`. Run your test on application to book a taxi on appium1 and on the receiving end see if you are getting any booking.

Comment: Actually you don't require two threads. Start appium in two different statements like - ```self.driver1 = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)```
and ```self.driver2 = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4727/wd/hub', desired_caps2)```